# How can make object in laravel to use in JavaScript laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJd6f.png)I want to get an object in this style

```
var zoz2= {
            "11-30--0001": "<a href=\"https:\/\/www.dooz.ps\/p\/107229\" >\u0625\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0633\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062e\u0627\u0645\u0633 \u0644\u0628\u0631\u0646\u0627\u0645\u062c \"\u062a\u0645\u064a\u0651\u0632\" <\/a>",
        };
```

i want to declarate  it in laravel,
i tried this but failed

```
$z=response()->json([
                "01-06-2019" => "<a href='https://www.dooz.ps/p/112996' >معرض وجوه للأقنعة</a>"
            ]);
```

then in JavaScript

```
console.log('{!! $z !!}');
```

but failed, 
In short, I want to get a data show in the console this way,
how to Declarate here at the php
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJd6f.png
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt39J.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve it,
in laravel must writ like this

```
$z=collect();
$z->put('06-16-2019', "<a href='/intvi/anylink' >معرض وجوه للأقنعة</a>");
....
$z=json_encode($z);
```

and use it in javascript

```
JSON.parse(` {!! $z !!}`)
```

Comment: You don't need the `JSON.parse` (and I suspect it'll break in some cases). You can just do `var zoz2 = {!! $z !!};`